# How is the Open Id token secured using Implicit Flow

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3

I have an Angular JS application and am using Identity Server 3 as my identity provider.

The user is redirected to the Identity Server via javascript to obtain a token e.g.

```
https://accounts.domain.eu/connect/authorize?client_id=MyApplicationId&redirect_uri=https://www.domain.eu&response_type=id_token%20token...
```

Following successful authentication, IdentityService redirects back to the supplied `redirect_uri` with a 302 that will redirect the browser and a `location` header containing e.g.

```
https://www.domain.eu/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGc...
```

Am I correct in assuming this is secure as the `location` header value will be encrypted using HTTPS and will not be available to someone looking at what HTTP requests were made?

Answer (score 1):

The transport channel should be protected by HTTPS - yes.

Answer (score 0):

While the HTTP 302 response from the Identity Server to the browser is secured by the usage of HTTPS, the ID Token won't be sent to the target application as it's a [Fragment Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), it will/has to be handled on the client (browser) side.

This is also in line with the purpose of the Implicit Flow, which is primarily for Javascript clients.